# Optimizing LINQ Select statement for better performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following Linq codes

```
   public partial class DBClass
    {
      public static IEnumerable<UserPrivilege> Select()
      {
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

        return db.UserPrivileges;
      }

     public static IEnumerable<UserPrivilege> SelectPage(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
     {
       return Select().Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);
     }

     public static int SelectCount()
     {
       return Select().Count();
     }

 }
```

I'm not really good at this. I just felt that the static method 'Select()' will pull the entire records in the 'UserPrivilege' table which might cause redundancy as not all the rows will be required most times for other tables. How best can I do this for better performance?

Comment: `"I just felt that the..."` - You can test this instead of guessing.  Profile the SQL server and see what actually gets executed when the code runs.  A lot of what you're doing here uses delayed execution and doesn't actually do anything against the database until the results of the query are materialized in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: change the `IEnumerable` to `IQueryable` in each place shown in the examples. Job done. Then it can compose as TSQL rather than in memory. Your count, for example, could cause everything to come over the wire rather than issuing a `select count(1)`

Comment: Are you sure about that? IQueryable is already an IEnumerable, and as long as the query doesn't prematurely execute a ToList, Count, Max or similar, it should stille compose an SQL query

Comment: From the query, how do I create alias for each column ?

Comment: @sondergard yes, I'm sure. Calling .Count, .Skip, or .Take on a sequence is **totally different** to calling them on a query.

Comment: @Wale a projection can be done with `select` - but beyond that I'm unclear on the question you are asking

Comment: I tried doing this `var PriviLedges = from Pri in db.UserPrivileges
select new
{
ID = Pri.PrivilegeID,
Name = Pri.PrivilegeName
}`
I get a cast error. saying cannot cast the type 'AnonymousType#1' to   IQueryable.

Comment: @Wale yes, you can't expose anonymous types in method signatures - so that isn't possible, but it is equally impossible for ienumerable and iqueryable. That's basically a different question. Simplest answer: declare a bespoke class that has the properties you want.